# I want to know how to find the data utilization for an interface for last 10 days

Tags: routing

I configured a VPN tunnel between 2 locations, and I provided access to VM machines from one point to other. I want to know the data utilization for a few systems. How do I find data utilization for these machines for an interval of 10 days?

Comment: Check to log files for the routers where you configured the tunnel interfaces? Clear the interface counters, then check after 10 days?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough information on the hardware used. But if your "routers" support snmp you could use something like mrtg or some other vendor solution to monitor your interfaces.

Here is an example of a similar question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/535875/how-to-monitor-per-port-bandwidth-using-snmp